# Android rotate text

Tags: android, canvas, rotation

Не понимаю как вращать текст.

**Есть код**

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new RotateText(this));
    }

    private class RotateText extends View {

        private Paint fontPaint;
        private String mText = "Rotate text";
        private int fontSize = 100;
        private float[] widths;

        public RotateText(Context context) {
            super(context);
            fontPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            fontPaint.setTextSize(fontSize);
            fontPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

            width = fontPaint.measureText(mText);

            widths = new float[mText.length()];
            fontPaint.getTextWidths(mText, widths);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            canvas.drawARGB(80, 102, 204, 255);

            canvas.translate(350, 550);

            canvas.drawText(mText, 0, 0, fontPaint);

        }
    }
}
```

Как заставить этот текст постоянно крутиться, желательно с заданным ускорением.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте это

```
ObjectAnimatior.ofFloat(view,"rotation",0,360).start();
```

или на худой конец это

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1600"
    android:fromDegrees="358"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:toDegrees="0" />
```

Также можете так

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

float angle = (float) (System.currentTimeMillis() % ROTATE_TIME_MILLIS) 
   / ROTATE_TIME_MILLIS * 360;
matrix.reset();
matrix.postTranslate(-source.getWidth() / 2, -source.getHeight() / 2);
matrix.postRotate(angle);
matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY)
canvas.drawBitmap(source, matrix, null);
invalidate(); // Cause a re-draw
```

Вот тебе кусок кода

```
Bitmap bmpLayered = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpMain.getWidth(), bmpMain
                .getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas cv = new Canvas(bmpLayered);

Paint charPaint = new Paint();
        charPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        charPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        charPaint.setTextSize(24);
        charPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        charPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);

cv.drawText("None", 570, 222, charPaint);
```

//--------------------------

```
   cv.save();
    cv.rotate(-45, x, y);
    cv.drawText("your text here", x, y, paint);
    cv.restore();
```

где cv ссылается на ваш холст, x & y, где вы хотите рисовать.
Так же можно сделать

```
cv.rotate(45f);

cv.rotate(45f, 100, 100);
```

и вот вам послендний пример госпади)

```
public class SView extends View {

    Paint p,paint; 
    public SView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(Color.RED);
        p.setTextSize(40);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setTextSize(40);
    }
  @Override 
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      super.onDraw(canvas);
      int cx = this.getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
      int cy = this.getMeasuredHeight() / 2;

      canvas.drawText("3AM", cx, cy, paint);
      canvas.save(); 

      canvas.scale(1f, -1f, cx, cy);
      canvas.drawText("3AM", cx, cy, p);
      canvas.restore();
}
}
```

на выходе получите такое 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот по 3 способу, нужен именно он. canvas.drawBitmap(source, matrix, null); Там первый параметр требует Bitmap, как его со строкой то совместить?

Comment: Вот прошу .Если вам понарвится мой ответ или поможет то прошу сделаь палец вверх)

Comment: Развёрнуто конечно, спасибо.